# Cypress Browserstack

Tags: cypress, browserstack

I have questions about cypress and BrowserStack
Will anyone have any idea how can I use the argument of --browser in browserstack-cypress run --
browser Chrome@latest: Windows 10, Firefox@latest-1:OS X Catalina command. But this command is not working, I got the error in error: Build creation failed. Error: Chrome latest on Windows is not supported in BrowserStack. See the list of supported browser versions and OS here: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress/browsers-and-os

Not sure why it will be that. Will anyone can help me with this? I will very appreciate it.

Office doc of BrowserStack for the BrowserStack-cypress run command.
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress/cli-reference#generate-configuration-file

Answer (score 0):

Try using

browserstack-cypress run --browser chrome@latest:"Windows 10",firefox@latest-1:"OS X Catalina"